# Node.JS Data Input Stream

Tags: node.js, module, stream, extend

Is there a input stream extension so I can call methods like I am used to

For example

```
stdin.readData(function (err, buffer) { // err if an error event was created, buffer if this is just data, null to both if the end of the stream was reached.
    // Added bonuses would be other methods I am used to in Java
    // - readLine
    // - readFully
    // - readStringUtf8
    // - readInt, readDouble, readBoolean, etc.
})
```

The backend would be listening for `data`, `end`, and `error` events and automatically buffer them and just have them available for when I call `readData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality isn't hard to do. All you have to do is get hold of the ReadableStream prototype and implement the`.read`method

**Untested Code:**

```
var ReadableStream = Object.getPrototypeOf(process.stdin);

ReadableStream.read = function(cb) {
    this.on('data', function(buf) {
        cb(null, buf);
    });

    this.on('error', function(err) {
        cb(err, null);    
    });

    this.on('end', function() {
        cb(null, null);
    });

    this.on('close', function() {
        cb(new Error("Stream closed"), null);
    });
};
```

Comment: Actually, `cb` would have to only be called once per call to `read`. The above code is not sufficient. I will write my own, just wondered if there was already one out there that might have additional features like readFully.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey a quick search on npm for "read" found [Line-reader](https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader/). I dont personally know any credible code bases for this functionality but there should be some out there (even if they are undocumented)